# Sheimos in newspapers and parsha sheets

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, genizah-storage

How should one dispose of Jewish newspapers, newsletters, children's parsha sheets, etc. that contain Divrei Torah? I believe some poskim require/allow it to be double wrapped and then left outside to be picked up -- what is the reasoning behind that view? And is the halachah more stringent if parts of actual pesukim are quoted?

Comment: Similar discussion here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/159/do-photocopies-of-torah-need-to-be-put-in-shaimos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excerpted from [Rabbi Heinemann's guidelines](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-mitzvos-shaimos.htm) (note that if something has an actual name of G-d, that's a separate set of issues; here we're assuming it's Torah but not the name of G-d):

*How should one dispose of Jewish newspapers, newsletters, children's parsha sheets, etc. that contain Divrei Torah?*

> **Newspapers and magazines** which contain secular information should not be put into shaimos ... The pages that have Torah may be removed and put into shaimos, **or the whole paper may be wrapped in paper and then placed in a plastic cover, kli besoch kli, and placed into the garbage.**

(I'd heard similarly from Rabbi Welcher.  I think it helps that it's not an entire book/newspaper designed for teaching Torah, just a tiny piece of it.  The respect due to Torah-teaching material is different than the prohibition of defacing the name of G-d; thus Torah material shouldn't sit with rotten eggs and coffee grounds, but if you double-bagged it that's okay.  I think an RJJ article a while back proposed aggregating this type of sheimos and recycling it.)

> Homework and test papers in Limudei Kodesh may be shaimos depending on whether [they are] ...
>
> **Paper on which a halacha is printed or written with intention to tell the halacha, a commentary of the Tanach, Mishna, Gemara, Rishonim, and Acharonim or a medrash of Chazal which is intended to explain a posuk or to teach us how to conduct ourselves in mussar or hashkafa.**

(See the article for more.)

If I understand the article, I think it depends on the homework sheet.  If it contains a large, direct quotation from Tanach, then yes.  If the sheet itself teaches something, then yes.  Otherwise not.

*And is the halachah more stringent if parts of actual pesukim are quoted?*

Yes if it's teaching Scripture; no if it's just Biblical paraphrasing to make a point (very common in rabbinic Hebrew).

> A paper on which three consecutive words of a posuk from Tanach have been written in one line with the intention of quoting the Tanach (as opposed to a melitzah which is not shaimos). Invitations from organizations and individuals that contain parts of pesukim are shaimos, however, the sentence Od Yishama, as frequently included in wedding invitations, is a melitzah, not intended to explain the posuk.

Comment: It is unclear from that article when "double bagging" is permitted. Do homework papers qualify?

Comment: I think the above article suggests double bagging only for items that are secular with some Torah content.  My impression is that other poskim might allow double-bagging in broader cases as well, but I can't cite anything offhand.