# What are the practical limits of shaimos in the common era?

Tags: halacha, technology, shemos-sacred-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hashems name on device](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/hashems-name-on-device)

I've tried to always be careful in regard to shaimos, but I'm still having difficulty understanding how it maps out in the age of the computer.

Does a representation of a holy name when transmitted electronically count as shaimos? Is there a difference as to whether it's represented in a font or is "baked" as an  image? Can one delete a file from his computer which has a holy name in it? It would seem that this would be a big issue if true, because of the way modern browsers work in regards to the caching mechanism; images and text are stored locally on the computer for a given amount of time, then discarded to free space when needed.

Comment: The second question has already been dealt with at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2771 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/159 (and were that not true, should probably be a separate question anyway), sO I'm taking the liberty of removing it herefrom, leaving only the first.

Comment: see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/hashems-name-on-device and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7275/is-it-permissible-to-erase-the-name-of-g-d-from-an-e-reader