# Does closing a browser with His name count as a sin?

Tags: halacha, technology, internet, shemos-sacred-names, melacha-erasing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hashems name on device](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/hashems-name-on-device)
>   [Is it permissible to erase the name of G-d from an E-reader?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7275/is-it-permissible-to-erase-the-name-of-g-d-from-an-e-reader)
>   [What are the practical limits of shaimos in the common era?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10777/what-are-the-practical-limits-of-shaimos-in-the-common-era)

Forgive me if I get some of the conventions wrong in this question; I'm a non-Jew.  After listening to the "This American Life" podcast, specifically
episode [#332](http://www.thisamericanlife.org/radio-archives/episode/332/the-ten-commandments).  I was struck by the story of young Shalom and how his
rabbi would not permit him to write his name on papers.  My understanding of the situation is that it is a sin to destroy the name of God unless it
is done in an approved way.

Given that the internet contains many places where the name of God is referenced, is the act of closing the browser a sin since it is technically removing
that word from the screen?  I'm assuming that since the information still exists somewhere (on the remote side server) that the information hasn't technically
been destroyed.  However, at some point the pages will be revised, the wording will change, and perhaps the name of God will be removed in those future pages.

Is this a huge grey area in the realm of shemos or am I not looking at this from the right angle?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin He's asking the [admittidly simpler] question of regular screens not E-readers.

Comment: This is a better dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10777/759

Comment: @DoubleAA more likely http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/hashems-name-on-device

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Not according to msh210's comment there :)

Comment: @DoubleAA then he should open the closed and close the open

Comment: Peter, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here.  As you can see from the other comments, this question has come up in a few different forms in the past, and we probably ought to merge all of them together.  But the short answer is that displaying the divine name in pixels on a screen isn't "writing", halachically speaking, so erasing doesn't apply.

Comment: just some resources -- i didn't look through the other questions  Avnei Yushfei 4:105, Teshuvos V’hanhugos 3:326, Ginzei Hakodesh page 298:19 quoting the opinion of
Horav Elyashiv Shlita. Refer to Laws of Pesach A Digest 5766:page 727.Rabbi Mordechai Friedman, "the Sanctity of God's Name: Erasing
Sacred Texts from a Computer Screen" in Alei EtZion: A Torah Periodical of
Yeshivat Har EtZion, Volume 8, Adar 5759, p. 47-55

Comment: @Dan I think that those sources are *a bit* too over-the-head of the OP.

Comment: I see now that there are quite a few duplicates of this question, thanks to everyone for the clarification!  My intellectual curiosity has been sated; thanks for the warm welcome and the wealth of info on this topic.

Comment: For the record, I recommend that you not take everything you hear about Judaism or Jewish culture in a Shalom Auslander story at face value. I've noticed multiple times in which it seems to me that he's applying some dramatic license to make his stories more interesting.

Comment: (Near-)duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35710