# Saying shalom as a greeting

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

Being that the word shalom in the greeting "shalom aleikhem" is G.ods name — can one omit the word aleikhem and just say shalom as a greeting ?

Comment: Not in the mikva

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16107