# Why do the laws of kevod seforim apply to physical seforim but not digital?

Tags: jewish-books, halacha-theory, technology, bathroom, kavod

I may have some trouble asking this question. I understand that the laws of kavod seforim (respecting holy texts; i.e., not bringing a book of Torah into the bathroom) do not apply to tapes, etc. (Source: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/weekly_torah.php?id=250). Presumably, they would also not apply to a phone that has Torah apps or downloads.

But why? And where is that line drawn? For example, if I had Torah on an e-ink reader, could that be in the bathroom if it were on? (/off?) In what respects is the distinction today drawn between virtual and physical?

(For official answers, please bring sources!)

Comment: highly related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1186/759 (and its linked questions).

Comment: Even that site (I assume) would agree the tape couldn't be playing in the bathroom. I think the point is data is irrelevant. Only when it is manifested physically in a way we can interact with do we treat it as Torah.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the Aruch Hashulchan writes that printed seforim dont have kedusha.

Comment: Hmmm - Does the Jewish Press have a digital version? Then maybe I actually CAN read it OUT of the bathroom :-)

Comment: This seems pretty much the same as http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10777, which was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @msh210 wow, that question should not have been closed

Comment: @DoubleAA But the halachos (AFAIK) are against the book's *being* in the bathroom, not against your *reading* it. Right? Therefore (one would think) data is in fact relevant

Comment: @mevaqesh Very interesting. If you can find the citation for that, it would make a great answer. Although it still seems most people don't bring seforim into the bathroom?

Comment: @SAH I don't follow your point. I didn't say anything about actually interacting with it. Just the potential. If something is interact-able then it deserves to be treated with respect. Whether it's printed or on a screen. As I said, "Only when it is manifested physically in a way we can interact with do we treat it as Torah."

Comment: @DoubleAA I was just drawing an analogy with "the tape being played" in your comment above. The equivalent of the tape being played would be the book being read -- at least I think so.

Comment: @SAH I don't. The book being read would be equivalent to the tape being listened to.