# Which articles have to go into shaimous?

Tags: halacha

What are the halachos of articles with Torah on them or Hashem's name, which can be thrown out and which need to be treated with care and be given to a organization that deals with it as shaimous?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/159/do-photocopies-of-torah-need-to-be-put-in-shaimos

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/sheimos-in-newspapers-and-parsha-sheets/2772#2772

Comment: what about pictures of rebbes that are very old? I feel like throwing them out even in a regular trash covered is disrespectful

Comment: @shmuel You mean you think representations of rebbes should be more stringent then representations of God???

Comment: I never said that. I was asking a question