# Do all printed kodesh materials require Geniza?

Tags: halacha, genizah-storage

Case 1: I print a english translation of something Kodesh.

Case 2: I *mistakenly* print out a few pages from a sefer. I have no intention of using those pages and do not learn from them.

Question:

Do all of the above printed materials need to go into Geniza? Is there any difference between things printed on a printer and those items that were printed on a proper printing press? (I don't think there is.)

Comment: How about case 4: I print out something which contains heresy, since I printed it and also contains divrei kodesh, is it shemos?

Comment: In regards to using a press vs. a printer: a press takes significantly more work, meaning that presumably you intended to print it out, whereas for a printer you might accidentally have hit [apple]+P

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14913/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/159/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2771/759

Comment: Thanks. I added the geniza tag to the relevant links to make it easier for others to find them.

Comment: I believe it is not about printed or written but more if it contains the Name of G-d or not.